# RewriteEngine on casuses error 500

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I am tring to write a rewrite engine. 
So I have written this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule     ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

I get a 500 error msg.

I checked the httpd.conf file and this line

```
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
```

is not commented out..

I also tried to comment out all these line from the .htaccess file like so,

```
#RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

#RewriteRule     ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

but I still get a 500 error.
What else can I look at?

Comment: May I suggest to edit the title, as it was clearly NOT "RewriteEngine on" causing the 500 error in this case (as was already evident by the fact that commenting it the problem persisted, and as your answer demonstrates). So people like me who search for "RewriteEngine on causes 500 error" won't find this result which has nothing to do.

Comment: and also it would be good if you accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution- it has to be dsaved in a unix format and not a dos format.

open notpad++ ->Edit-> EOL convertion->unix format